# Eval() and expression code

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval

I have such code in ASP.NET web page but when I run it I get error.

```
>     Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only
> be used in the context of a databound control.
```

Where is the problem?

```
        <% if (Helpers.GetInt(Eval("Price")) != 0)
           { %>
        <input type="button" name="btnSignUp" value="Sign Up - Plimus »" onclick="window.location='<%#Eval("BuyUrl2")%><%= Common.GetUserIdUrl("&","custom_user_id") %>'" />       
         <%  } %>
```

I get error code on line

<% if (Helpers.GetInt(Eval("Price")) != 0)

I complete Repeater code is below. As I said early everything in this code works fine except `IF` statement. I want to evaluate `PRICE` and if it is `!=0` show button html code.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col title">
            <%#Eval("Title")%>
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <div class="col price">
            <%#string.Format("{0} USD/{1} </br> Instant activation", Helpers.GetDecimal(Eval("Price")).ToString("N"), Portal.GetMembershipTypeLabel(Helpers.GetInt(Eval("Credits"))))%>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="button" name="btnSignUp" value="Sign Up - PayPal »" onclick="window.location='<%#Eval("BuyUrl1")%><%= Common.GetUserIdUrl("&","custom_user_id") %>'" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <% if (Helpers.GetInt(Eval("Price")) != 0)
               { %>
            <input type="button" name="btnSignUp" value="Sign Up - Plimus »" onclick="window.location='<%= Eval("BuyUrl2")%><%= Common.GetUserIdUrl("&","custom_user_id") %>'" />       
             <%  } %>

        </div>
         <hr/>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Did you try: `<%=Eval("BuyUrl2")%>` instead?

Comment: @Icarus The exception appears at IF line

Comment: Tomas can you show your complete aspx file?

Answer (score 2):

yes, you are trying to use Eval in an HTML input control, which is not allowed as stated correctly by the error.

Eval or Bind and fellows are executed usually when you bind a data-boundable control like DataList, DataGrid, DataRepeater and so on because these commands (**Eval**...) are applied against the DataSource you are binding. doing so against a control like raw HTML input has no meaning because there is nothing to bind against.

notice that your call/usage of `<%= Common.GetUserIdUrl...` looks correct and can stay there :)

Comment: I use this code in Repeater and if I remove IF line everything works fine. <%#Eval("BuyUrl2")%> and <%= Common.GetUserIdUrl("&","custom_user_id") %> both are correct in this situation. The problem is in IF statement.